# Kali Linux Live USB boots into text mode. Unable to Start the GUI

Tags: boot, live-usb, kali-linux

I am booting kali Linux from the USB. But it boots me into Kali login prompt. When I provide the credentials for root. It gives me root prompt.root@kali. Any pointers please on how to boot into GUI mode using live USB. 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that you have added snapshots to your question: The data on this USB device is corrupt.  The reason you can not start X is because the libraries and/or binaries needed to start gdm3 can not be read by the Linux kernel.

To resolve this, reinstall Kali Linux again, ideally on a different USB device.

Comment: +1 and thanks a lot :) I initially tried formatting the USB but that did not work. I bought the new USB per your suggestion and it did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Logon and try `startx`. Or `service gdm3 start`

Then you just have to open the file /etc/inittab as root, and add the following line at the end of the file:

```
x:5:respawn:/usr/sbin/gdm -nodaemon
```

If gdm3 is not a part of Kali, try installing it with:

```
apt-get -f install gdm
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your inputs. I tried above approaches but still facing the issues as shown in snapshots attached.

Comment: Now things look different. And yes, in your specific case, follow samiam advice.

Answer (score 0):

**Text mode to Graphical Mode:**

I have recently faced a problem with my kali linux, The problem is that i can't get into graphical mode, When ever i reboot my kali its starts in terminal mode(tty3) and asked root password when i typed password it still shows me text. i tried many things to get into graphical mode.

Typing **Startx** to enter into graphical mode but it is used in backtrack not in kali. Later i tried pressing control+alt+f7 but still it didn't worked.

After searching all websites and blogs i noticed many things
Like some told to type "use fsck command then reboot, first login by entering your password"

I tried fsck and came back with an error **e2fsck cannot continue, aborting**

And even tried gdm3 but it didn't worked

At some point i decided to reinstall the KALI. But i feared to lost the files in which i saved.

but don't worry about it in your case I will give you real solution for that

Before typing `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` to install missing files

Let's check the Network connectivity by following steps, type the following command as it is..

```
service networking start
service network-manager start
service samba start
dhclient eth0
```

(`ifconfig` to check the *net interface configuration is ok and eth0 is working right*)

Then type  `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`

---

Next install `chkconfig` if its not installed through `apt-get install chkconfig`

Then check the status of level 2 of gdm3 using `chkconfig --level 2 gdm3`

Install `gdm3` service if it's not installed using `apt-get install gdm3`

When I typed gdm3 it showed me "bash: gdm3:command not found",
then I typed  `sudo apt-get install gdm3`

after installing I just typed `gdm3` in the terminal. Then it directly taken me to the graphical mode.

Answer (score 0):

As seen in your screenshot above, your issue was that you typed apt-get -f install gdm - and you should have typed gdm3.

Comment: you didn't see that the culprit was a defect USB-drive?